# Response.Write parts of html

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a huge HTML table (not table really but div's) that is generating and loading realy long to the browser. So I decided to try to render this table by parts. I mean to render rows as they are ready at the server side. Using this the user can see some information at the page even if it is not fully genereted on server side.

I tried to play with HTTP handler and

```
context.Response.Write
context.Response.Flush();
```

But without any luck.
Can anybody please help me with streaming this html parts from server side to the client?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC 3 doesn't work like this with Response.Write etc. Could you please explain why the table is so huge and why you use divs?

Comment: Not actual now. It works as I moved this handler to a new project. It doesnn't work in old one. Investigating....

Comment: You could try to do server paging. Or to load the data using multiple AJAX requests.

Comment: Rhapsody: ASP.NET MVC 3 really doesn't work like this. The page needs to be fully rendered at the server side then returned to IIS then to user. But you can do this tricks using HttpHandler, it works. Why my table is so huge? So it's about 5 megs of financial data and the Customer doesn't want paging. It's also hard to implement ajax loading caz of table has ability to group records with subtotal allocation.

Comment: Vladimir Perevalov: Paging is not acceptable by customer, Multiple ajax request not needed since i can load the page in Stream.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, can you render the full output on the server side, store it in session, then make multiple ajax calls to retrieve the data in pieces. This would fulfill both requirements of server-side rendering and enabling the user to see the first part of the page immediately.

Is this even a feasible idea?

Comment: Not bad idea but it seems to me that multiple ajax calls will process much more slower than the one stream of rendered html content. The other issue is: how to render MVC controls from HTTP handler

Comment: True. But the core problem you are trying to solve is the extremely large file size you are returning to the user (5MB). As far as the user is concerned it will be quicker and more responsive. The speed difference is irrelevant to the user.  In regards to how to render MVC controls from HTTP handler, I'm confident its been done before.